# Is this language defined using twin primes regular?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-languages, finite-automata

Let

$\qquad L = \{a^n \mid \exists_{p \geq n}\ p\,,\ p+2 \text{ are prime}\}.$

Is $L$ regular?

This question looked suspicious at the first glance and I've realized that it is connected with the [twin prime conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime). My problem is that the conjecture has not been resolved yet, so I am not sure how can I proceed with deciding that the language is regular.

Comment: Note that if $P=\{a^p:p,p+2\in\mathbb{P}\}$ then $L$ is a quotient: $L=P/a^{\ast}$ (or, it is the set of prefixes of $P$). In general, for any unary language $P$ the language $P/a^{\ast}$ is regular.

Comment: An amusing variant is $L = \{ a^p : p \text{ and } p+2 \text{ are prime} \}$. This is regular iff the twin prime conjecture is false.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the twin prime conjecture is true, then $L = a^{*}$, which is regular. If the twin prime conjecture is not true, then there are finitely many twin primes; indeed, there is a largest pair of twin primes $\{p, p + 2\}$. In this case, $L = \{a^{n} | n < p + 1\}$, a finite language. In either case, you get a regular language, so I think it's safe to conclude that $L$ is a regular language... we just won't know which one it is until the twin prime conjecture is resolved.

Comment: <been doing too much intuitionistic logic> Could the twin prime conjecture be undecidable?

Comment: @Gilles Is undecidable really the correct term here? Either there are infinitely many twin primes or there are not.

Comment: @ZachLangley Not necessarily: the twin prime conjecture (TP) could be [undecidable (in the sense of independent from usual mathematical axioms)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28mathematical_logic%29). But my comment was a joke (impossible to get if you don't know what [intuitionistic logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic) is; in fact, from “TP or not TP”, we can deduce “$L$ is finite or $L$ is $L=a^*$”, so $L$ is regular anyway.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, this language is regular. The twin prime conjecture need not be resolved in order to see this:

Suppose the twin prime conjecture is true, that is, for any $n$, we can find a prime $p \geq n$ such that $p+2$ is prime. Then in particular, $L = \{ a^n | n \in N \}$, as the condition is always true. This last language is expressible by $a^*$ and hence regular.

Suppose the twin prime conjecture is false. Then there exists some $N$ such that there exists some prime $p$ such that $p+2$ is prime, and for every $n > N$, there exists no $p$ such that $p+2$ is prime. In this case, $L = \{ a^n | n \leq N \}$, which is a finite language, and therefore regular.

By case distinction, we conclude that $L$ is regular.

Answer (score 9):

It is regular in either case.

- If there are infinitely many twin primes, then $L=\{a^n:n\geq 0\}=L(a^*)$.
- If there are finitely many twin primes, then $L$ is finite, therefore regular.